# Toggle text color of all div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to change all the  text color to black when the checkobx is checked and back to their original color when unchecked?

I tried the using toggle but am not sure how to retain the original color.
The current code is below and here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/5stqtzw6/1/).

Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="ws-css-table">
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">A</div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">C</div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">E</div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td">F</div>
    </div>
</div>

    </br>
<input type="checkbox" id="blacktext">Black Text
```

jquery

```
 var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green'];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.ws-css-table-td').each(function ()
 {      
  var theColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $(this).css('color', theColor);
});
    });
```

css:

```
.ws-css-table {
    display: table;
}
.ws-css-table-tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.ws-css-table-td {
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 15px;
    height:15px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green'];

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ws-css-table-td').each(function() {
     var theColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
     $(this).css('color', theColor);
   });
 });


 $('#blacktext').click(function() {

   $('.ws-css-table-td').toggleClass('blackcolor');

 })
```

```css
.ws-css-table {
  display: table;
}
.ws-css-table-tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.ws-css-table-td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.blackcolor {
  color: #000!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ws-css-table">
  <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
    <div class="ws-css-table-td">A</div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-td">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
    <div class="ws-css-table-td">C</div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-td">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
    <div class="ws-css-table-td">E</div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-td">F</div>
  </div>
</div>

</br>
<input type="checkbox" id="blacktext">Black Text
```

Comment: Thanks I knew there must be a way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a onclick, add to the checkbox:

```
onclick="makeBlack"
```

Now we are gonna make a function in javascript called makeBlack:

```
function makeBlack() {  
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ws-css-table-td");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was hoping to be able to retain the original text color if the checked the box again.